# Why is the PE format position dependent?

Tags: portable-executable

Is there any good reason that an executable file needs a preferred loading address and therefore persist of position dependent code instead of simply using RVAs all over the file?
For me this looks like a major design flaw, I don't understand how one would even come up with this idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess the reason is more historical than practical.

Citing Matt Pietrek, from his well known "[Peering Inside the PE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx)":

> It's common knowledge that Windows NT has a VAX® VMS® and UNIX®
>   heritage. Many of the Windows NT creators designed and coded for those
>   platforms before coming to Microsoft. When it came time to design
>   Windows NT, it was only natural that they tried to minimize their
>   bootstrap time by using previously written and tested tools. The
>   executable and object module format that these tools produced and
>   worked with is called COFF (an acronym for Common Object File Format).
>   [...]  The COFF format by itself was a good starting point, but needed
>   to be extended to meet all the needs of a modern operating system like
>   Windows NT or Windows 95. The result of this updating is the Portable
>   Executable format.

So the PE format is based on the COFF format, and the later has the concept of [relocations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable#Relocations): they allow the system (more precisely the system's Loader) to rebase a PE at runtime by patching position dependent addresses.

The [official PE documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463119.aspx) explicitly names Relocations as "COFF Relocations" so I guess the PE relocations are inherited from COFF and are not a new addition brought by the PE format itself.

All in all, my guess is that a position independant PE was discarded (if even ever considered) as the COFF format has already the concept of relocations which achieve the same feature.

Comment: PIC is a significant burden in 32bit code that access static data (like constants or lookup tables), where RIP-relative addressing is not available.  It's much cheaper to have addresses hard-coded into the machine instructions.  So either code has to jump through hoops to be position-independent, or it has to have all those addresses rewritten every time it's loaded.  The 2nd way would require loading/relocating the whole executable at load time, and it would be a private copy for that process (rather than a shared read-only mapping of the executable on disk).

Comment: So there are actually significant performance reasons for making position-dependent code on 32bit x86.